# JNLP Slave connection failure

Tags: jenkins

I am a beginner to the kubernetes setup.

Here is the setup that we have - Jenkins Master running on kubernetes cluster - has only one kube node. The Jenkins application is exposed through a "NodePort" on pot 32083. The Jenkins master web UI is accessed through a VIP configured on port 32083. Hence the Jenkins URL at https:// is served through the VIP on port 32083.

I can access the Jenkins webui and it works as expected. I have configured external ubuntu slaves for handling the builds.These slaves work as expected.

I am now trying to configure an external windows VM as the slave. All K8s, ubuntu slaves and windows slaves use JDK8

Here is the helm chart values.yaml for the UI port and the slavelistener.

ServicePort: 8080
ServiceType: NodePort
NodePort: 32083
ServiceAnnotations: {}
ContainerPort: 8080
SlaveListenerPort: 50000 
Here is the config at the loadbalancer:

```
ltm virtual -50000 { description -50000 destination :50000 ip-protocol tcp mask x.x.x.x pool pool--50000 profiles { http-xforwarded-xproto-https { } tcp { } xxx-clientssl { context clientside } }

ltm pool pool-xxxxx-50000 { members { :32083 { address x.x.x.x session monitor-enabled state up } :32083 { address x.x.x.x session monitor-enabled state up } } monitor http }
```

Here is the error i get when i try to launch the Java webstart slave JNLP from the windows VM

```
INFO: Protocol JNLP4-connect encountered an unexpected exception java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol ConnectionRefusalException: Connection closed before acknowledgement sent hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status INFO: Agent discovery successful Agent address: xxxx Agent port: 50000 Identity: xxxxx

hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status INFO: Handshaking hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status INFO: Connecting to xxxx:50000 hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status INFO: Trying protocol: JNLP4-connect hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status INFO: Protocol JNLP4-connect encountered an unexpected exception java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.ConnectionRefusalException: Connection closed before acknowledgement sent at org.jenkinsci.remoting.util.SettableFuture.get(SettableFuture.java:22 3) at hudson.remoting.Engine.innerRun(Engine.java:614) at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:474) Caused by: org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.ConnectionRefusalException: Conn ection closed before acknowledgement sent at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.AckFilterLayer.onRecvClosed(AckF ilterLayer.java:280) at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.ProtocolStack$Ptr.onRecvClosed(Protoc olStack.java:816)
```

I have even changed the loadbalancer config to look like this

```
ltm pool pool--50000 { members { :50000 { address x.x.x.x session monitor-enabled state up } :50000 { address x.x.x.x session monitor-enabled state up } } monitor http }
```

Also set the -Dhudson.TcpSlaveAgentListener.hostName= during Jenkins start. Also set the "Tunnel connection through" to ":" in the Windows slave node configuration.

End up getting the same error as above every time. Any configuration at the Kubernetes setup or loadbalancer that I am missing here?